# Extracting data from nested dicts and lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

Say I have a dict that looks like this:

```
dic = {'outer_key_1': {'inner_key_1': [1, 2, 3],
                       'inner_key_2': [4, 5, 6],
                       'inner_key_3': [7, 8, 9]}, 
       'outer_key_2': {'inner_key_1': [11, 12, 13],
                       'inner_key_2': [14, 15, 16],
                       'inner_key_3': [17, 18, 19]}}
```

My goal is to extract the first element of every inner dict, ending up with a nested list:

```
[[1, 4, 7], [11, 14, 17]]
```

Or, alternatively, a dict like this:

```
{'outer_key_1': [1, 4, 7], 'outer_key_2': [11, 14, 17]}
```

I have tried getting there with nested list comprehensions, but the best I could come up with is a non-nested list of the result values (more or less `[1, 4, 7, 11, 14, 17]` except that the values get mixed up, which should be easy to fix by using an OrderedDict instead). Here is a rather ugly solution using for loops, but I'm sure someone here can come up with something better.

```
# TODO: find a better way to do this
result = []
for inner_dict in dic.values():
    result.append([l[0] for l in inner_dict.values()])
print(result)
```

which prints (once again, values are mixed up, but that's not the problem at hand):

```
[[14, 17, 11], [4, 7, 1]]
```

What would be the most elegant way to solve that? I'm pretty new to python, so any hints on how to approach that problem are appreciated. I have also tried experimenting with `zip`, which I think should be a pretty nice way to do it, but I still need to wrap my head around how to use that together with list comprehensions, so... Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that dicts aren't sorted by default in Python. If you need the inner dicts in a specific order, you should first sort them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you mean by elegance, but to me, the following is quite elegant if you understand functional programming well

```
[zip(*e)[0] for e in map(dict.values, dic.values())]
```

So what it does

- `dic.values()` returns a list of values in the dictionary
- `map(dict.values, dic.values())` returns a second level nested values in the dictionary
- finally for each list of nested values, transpose it using `zip` and fetch the first row, which infact is the first column in the deeply nested dict.

If you want to optimize further

1. Replace `map` with `itertools.imap`
2. If you are still in Python 2.X, replace `dict.values` with `dict.itervalues`

Comment: Yeah, that definitely looks elegant. However, I am having some trouble with that when I run it in an IPython notebook (2.7.5+):

`TypeError: values() takes no arguments (1 given)`

It works fine when I run it from the command line though. Interestingly, when I run the same thing in 3.3.2+, I get another error:

`TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable`

Any idea why that is?

Comment: Regarding `However, I am having some trouble with that when I run it in an IPython notebook (2.7.5+):`, I cannot confirm now, as I do not have an IPython installation at my disposal. Regarding `when I run the same thing in 3.3.2`, as Py 3.X `zip` returns an iterator, you need to convert it to a list before indexing `[list(zip(*e))[0] for e in map(dict.values, dic.values())]`

Comment: My bad... turns out I had overwritten `dict` at some point, hence the error. Your code does in fact work for 2.7, and thanks for the clarification regarding 3.x.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
>>> {outerKey: [innerVal[0] for innerVal in outerVal.itervalues()] for outerKey, outerVal in dic.iteritems()}
{'outer_key_1': [4, 7, 1], 'outer_key_2': [14, 17, 11]}
```

That is a dictionary comprehension with a list comprehension inside.  The outer dict comprehension iterates over the key-alue pairs of the outer dict.  The inner list comprehension makes a list of the first item in each inner value (i.e., each list in the inner dict).

If you want a list instead just make the dict comprehension into a list comprehension (removing the reference to the outer key):

```
>>> [[innerVal[0] for innerVal in outerVal.itervalues()] for outerKey, outerVal in dic.iteritems()]
[[14, 17, 11], [4, 7, 1]]
```

Note that you cannot control the order of the lists, because the original dict is unordered.

Comment: That looks nice, is there a reason you are using itervalues() and iteritems() instead of values() and items()?

Comment: @SebastianHofer: In Python 2, it can save memory if the source dict is large.  If you use `values()` it generates a list of all the values up-front, whereas with `itervalues()` it only grabs one at a time.  In Python 3 the plain `values()` method works like Python 2's `itervalues()` (and likewise for iterkeys and iteritems).

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries in Python are not sorted by default. If the order is important, you can sort before  you get the values.

```
result = []
for inner_dict in sorted(dic.values()):
    res = []
    for l in sorted(inner_dict.values()):
        res.append(l[0])
    result.append(res)

print(result)
# Output: [[1, 4, 7], [11, 14, 17]]
```

If you need to use the dictionaries as sorted entities beyond this, it might be a good idea to look into using an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), which keeps them in order by default.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `zip` to transpose the values:

```
[ (list(zip(*d.values())[0])) for d in dic.values()]
[[14, 17, 11], [4, 7, 1]]
```

If you want sorted output:

```
[(list(zip(*sorted(d.values()))[0])) for d in sorted(dic.values())]
```